# Почему Glide не уменьшает изображение?

Tags: android, picasso

Имеется набор из шести `ImageButton` c заданными параметрами ширины и высоты
Эти параметры могу изменятся в зависимости от того на каком устройстве отображаются кнопки, но в данным момент они постоянны, так как устройство одно и то же.
А так же 6 изображений размером `200 х 200`

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/RG_SS_Button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

При использовании `Picasso` для наполнения всех 6 кнопок используется следующий код

```
Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[0]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton1);
        Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[1]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton2);
        Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[2]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton3);
        Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[3]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton4);
        Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[4]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton5);
        Picasso.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[5]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fit().centerCrop().into(RG_SSButton6);
```

При этом автоматически определяется размер целевого объекта в который помещается изображение, изображение пропорционально уменьшается до этих размеров, а излишки обрезаются.

Все это отлично, но создает некоторую задержку, из-за того что время затрачивается на определение этих самих размеров объекта.

Теоретически этого недостатка лишен `Glide`, который определяет размеры автоматически, не теряя время на определение. Но почему то он не хочет вмещать изображение в кнопку полностью. 
Вместо этого он будто кладет туда картинку размером `200 х 200` и затем обрезает излишки.

```
 Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[0]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton1);
            Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[1]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton2);
            Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[2]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton3);
            Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[3]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton4);
            Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[4]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton5);
            Glide.with(RunGallery_SmallSpeed.this).load(RG_SS_V1[5]).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_white).fitCenter().into(RG_SSButton6);
```

Пробовал оба варианта. И `.fitCenter()` и `.centerCrop()`. Результат один и тот же.

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я использую неправильный метод или все таки `Glide` не способен в таком ключе работать с `ImageButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, действительно. При работе с `ImageButton`, `Glide` не может на лету распознать размеры целевого `view`. Для решения достаточно использовать `ImageView`.

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/RG_SS_Button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

И тогда нет необходимости даже указывать как именно следует вмещать изображение. За счет этого есть прирост в скорости отрисовки по сравнению с `Picasso`.

```
 Glide.with(this).load(RG_SS_V1[0]).into(RG_SSButton1);
```

Comment: Что-то я не понял, а как ты заменил свои ImageButton на  ImageView?

Comment: @ЛевНауменко взял и заменил, кнопку на изображение. Для android по сути не важно нажатия на что необходимо слушать.